# IC identification- Analog Devices IC with top marking "P 2A"

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Please help me to identify this IC. It is an Analog Devices chip in MSOP-8 package.

The top marking says "P 2A". It's used in a 8-inch LCD monitor and controls the brightness of the screen. It is quite difficult to identify that component, as AD uses different marking code for their devices.

[image: P 2A]

Answer (score 2):

According to [smdmark](http://www.smdmark.com/zh-CN/ic-181586.html) it is a ADP3040ARM, switching regulator.

[This post](https://ez.analog.com/power/w/documents/4647/adp3040---information-available) on the ADI engineer zone website details that is a customer specific part with no documentation freely available.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply